# Audio / Computer halts when wifi connecting

Tags: windows-7, windows

When the wifi is connecting, my computer halts briefly. The screen is momentarily frozen and the audio skips if I'm playing music. This happens consistently.

I occasionally experience the same issue while browsing the internet with chrome. While loading a page, the screen will freeze and the audio will skip and then everything's back to normal.

What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

The processor is an i5-3450

Comment: Look in the resource monitor (resmon.exe) when it occurs. I would be looking for something that hits the internet as soon as you re-establish the connection, so start in the Network tab of the resource monitor, for programs doing "network actitivity" on connect. Could be a AV program updating (then running) or some other things not even working very well.  Could be a disk waking back up from standby, so check with your power properties all off temporarily.  Supply more information about your machine and connection type, number and type of drives, the network interface model, and much more.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you should try to look for in this case:

1)Run Resource monitor - take a look for anything that is hogging your computer when you open a web browser.  It could be that your antivirus is aggressively scanning something when you open your browser

2)Try running a different antivirus - perhaps your one missed something and whatever has infected your computer is reporting whenever you open a browser

3)Try a different browser (or reinstalling your current one) - a corrupt profile or orther browser bug could be causing you issues.  Perhaps you also have too many tabs starting with your browser

4)Disable Addons - it is possible that the intense workload of loading an addon-heavy browser is too much for your PC

5)Try defragging your drive - if the PC is slowing due to your drive being fragmented, this could help somewhat.

Hope one of these helps.